# How to Read last line of a delimited File

Tags: c++

I have a delimited file with semi-colon delimiter.
I am using the following code to read the last line. I believe the loop runs until the last line and keeps overwriting the lastLine string. So once the last line is reached, the loop breaks and the string is the last line.

```
while(getline(finlocal, chuy, ';'))
{
       getline(finlocal,lastLine, ';');
}

cout<<lastLine; //last line.
```

But this method does not work properly and efficiently.
Any suggestions on How to know the last line of this delimited file.

Comment: What you  mean, it does not work properly?

Comment: what do you mean by `it doesn't work properly`??

Comment: Are you only interested in the last line or do you need all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
while(getline(finlocal, lastLine, ';'));
cout<<lastLine;
```

or otherwise you will might not get the last line.

you can use

```
    while(getline(finlocal, lastLine, ';'))
    {
       getline(finlocal,lastLine, ';');
    }
    cout<<lastLine;
```

but there is no point in doing `getline` twice

for a better delimiter in your case i would have used a special sign, say do:

```
char delimiter = 251;
```

that char is the sign for square root, and most probably won't be used in chat. still, for each chat message that arrives you need to check if the sign is in use there and if so delete it. now for each message you send, send with the sign at the end of it, and when receiving, split at that character with the `getline`.

that way you split easily in a place you know the user won't mess.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked guys but one problem. I take this last line and find the position of it in another file I have.
I use the following code:-
 `while (getline(myfile, line, ';'))
 {
       ++number_of_lines;
        if(stricmp(lastLineLocal.c_str(),line.c_str())==0)
         {
          break;
         }

 }`
It does give some value of the lines but it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @GPTBoss first of all you should edit your question or open a new one. second your code looks good. add printing of the values while comparing to get better insight to the problem and post it 2

Comment: @GPTBoss No need to post, the porblem is obvious. put ++number_of_lines  after if(){..} and it should work properl :). You probably get the number of line next to right line, right?

Comment: @khajvah that depend in how is he initiate number_of_lines after, but anyway, that's a different question and therefor deserve a question of it's own....

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I don't think that question will help others in future, so if he can solve it now, there is no point to open new question for that. What you mean how is he initiate number_of_lines after? I think the problem is obvious, it increments before checking, so even if the right line is found, the counter is incremented and so points to next line.

Comment: @khajvah i wouldn't that sure about it... it might just be that he did not see how many ";" he has, maybe several in one line and then it count it as several lines... anyway, we can't never be sure which question will be more helpful then others. for example take a look at the most voted question. it's not what you'd think it is

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Thanks for the remark and suggestions. 
Right now, i am not able to think of what to use to count the lines as either the code counts many ";" in single lines as one line.

Comment: @GPTBoss please edit the question or something so i can see the file, and i'll run it and give you an educated answer

Comment: @GPTBoss If you want to do it alone. A hint: get rid of ";" delimiter from getline and erase last ";"-s from string or update the post and wait for NoideaForName to do it...

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest to write `while(cond) {}` (or `while(cond){ ; }`, or `while(cond) continue;`) rather than `while(cond);` because that trailing semicolon (especially when glued to the closing parenthesis without even a space in between) is very likely to be missed by a reader and this is an infamous cause of _bugs_.

Comment: @gx_ i'll agree on that, but! if you add a comment on that line it'll be clear enough

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I'd rather simply write `while(cond){}`. _That_ is clear enough. Doesn't even need a comment.

Comment: @gx_ actually `while(cond){}` might be not clear because why is the loop empty? so here you'd also need to add comment...

Comment: i have changed the delimiter to the default line break due to many reasons though I would like to know your comments on what should I use. I am making a chat application that stores messages on files. These files are then uploaded to FTP server n then all other clients can connect to them as well. If you could suggest what would be the right way to efficiently store messages in file, I wud be pleased.

Comment: i have, but it's far too long to write here... amm, i'll edit the answer, even though it's wired i have all this chat going on on my answer but no +1 or -1 to tell if it's even a good one. 5 min and refresh the answer @GPTBoss

Answer (score 5):

You did not explain what is your problem but I guess it doesn't check every line because the getline() inside the loop points to next element, so you lose half of your elements.

```
while(getline(finlocal, chuy, ';'))
{

}
std::cout<<chuy;
```

should work

Let's say this is your lines:

1.; <--

2.;

3.;

4.;

...

after the first iteration it goes to:

1.; <--

2.; *<--(by while)*

3.; <--(by inside getline)

4.;

...

So you lose the 2nd element. Loop goes on and in the end

5.; <-- (by inside loop)

end.; <-- (by while): this assignes the right line to chuy and points to next element

which does not exist and so inside getline() doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if the file wouldn't be really big, you may first get the whole file in a string and use `string::find_last_of` to find the last index of semicolon. Then print the line from that index till end of file.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked guys but one problem. I take this last line and find the position of it in another file I have. I use the following code:- `while (getline(myfile, line, ';')) { ++number_of_lines; if(stricmp(lastLineLocal.c_str(),line.c_str())==0) { break; } }`
 It does give some value of the lines but it doesn't seem to be right.